# Creating a views reference list to be used in a node reference

Tags: views, nodes

I am using a view to create a limited list of nodes of a certain node type in a node reference. E.g. A logged in user may only select nodes she has created.

I am using a contextual filter in a references view. The contextual filter is set to:
Provide default value = User ID from logged in user
and:
Exception value = 1

So while a user may see her nodes only, the super user may see everything.

I like to add a third condition so that any user with the role of editor can see everything as well. Can anybody tell me how or point me in the right direction on how to approach this? I am running out of ideas.

Update: The exception actually doesn't work either. So the questions is: How can I create a references list where:

- the owner can see only her nodes
- UID 1 can see all nodes
- a user with role editor can see all nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can use entity reference module  (https://drupal.org/project/entityreference). It provides the forward and backward reference of views.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to filter by permission so that the user sees all nodes on which they have Edit permission. You may need to add a relationship to the user in the view.